# Using AFNetworking 2.0+ on OS X 10.8

Tags: afnetworking-2

Is there anyone successfully using AFNetworking 2.* on OS X 10.8? Its documentation says that minimal requirements is OS X 10.8 but I have no luck using it in application with deployment target and Base SDK 10.8.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown", referenced from:
      -[AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:] in libPods.a(AFURLSessionManager.o)
      -[AFURLSessionManager uploadTaskWithTask:progress:completionHandler:] in libPods.a(AFURLSessionManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libPods.a(AFURLSessionManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSessionConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libPods.a(AFHTTPSessionManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in libPods.a(AFURLSessionManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is it possible to use AFNetworking 2 on OS X 10.8?

Answer (score 1):

`AFNetworking 2.0` can be used on `OSX 10.8`, but you cannot use the classes based on `NSURLSession` (Available from `10.9`) Basically don't use `AFURLSessionManager & AFHTTPSessionManager` or even the constants defined in `NSURLSession`.

Use below:

```
AFURLConnectionOperation   
AFHTTPRequestOperation   
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
```